# Changing button colour in Acrobat form makes text invisible

Tags: adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

I'm trying to add buttons to save and print a PDF form (ideally just one specific page of it, but that's very much the ambitious option at the moment), but while the text on them is visible in the editor, it (along with the button borders) disappears in the fillable form.

[image: Buttons in the editor][image: Buttons in the saved file]

The only thing I have changed is the Fill Colour in the appearance settings:

[image: Appearance settings with changed fill colour]

Any idea what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only specified a name for your button, but the text which appears on a button is not its name, but the "Label".

This must be set in "Button Properties -> Options -> Label".

In my image, the name of the button is "Test Button" (set in the "General" tab), while the label is "Go to somewhere". The font options (set in the "Appearance" tab) will apply to the label, not to the name.

[image]

For further details, you might want to also check the appropriate [adobe acrobat help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/setting-action-buttons-pdf-forms.html)

Comment: Aaaaah! It's so simple and obvious when you put it that way. Adobe's nomenclature doesn't always gel with my brain. Thanks!